# Function to even out multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Assume I have a function

```
evenOut($array, $limit){
    //returns exactly $limit items
}
```

and this data

```
$animals = array();
$animals['barn'] = array_fill(0,20, 'b');
$animals['forest'] = array_fill(0,20, 'f');
$animals['house'] = array_fill(0,20, 'h');
$animals['mountain'] = array_fill(0,20, 'm');
```

I want to return a maximum of 10 animals, however they should be spread out evenly among the locations they come from.
so if i did
`evenOut($animals,8);` i'd get 2 of each`('b','b','f','f','h','h','m','m',)`
`evenOut($animals,2);` should return `('b','f')`

if I have this data

```
$animals = array();
$animals['barn'] = array_fill(0,1, 'b');
$animals['forest'] = array_fill(0,3, 'f');
$animals['house'] = array_fill(0,8, 'h');
$animals['mountain'] = array_fill(0,1, 'm');
```

`evenOut($animals,8);` expected result would be `('b','f','f','f','h','h','h','m',)`
`evenOut($animals,10);` expected result would be `('b','f','f','f','h','h','h','h','h','m',)`

```
$animals = array();
$animals['barn'] = array_fill(0,0, 'b');
$animals['forest'] = array_fill(0,3, 'f');
```

`evenOut($animals,10);` expected result would be `('f','f','f')`

I'm not sure how I should approach this, I am hoping there is a simple way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution

```
    function evenOut($array, $limit){
        $indexes = count($array)-1;
        $leveled = array();
        $count=0;
        for($c= 0; $c < $limit; $c++){
            for($i = 0; $i <= $indexes; $i++){
                if(isset($array[$i][$c])){
                    if(!isset($leveled[$i]))
                        $leveled[$i] = array();
                    $leveled[$i][]= $array[$i][$c];
                    $count++;

                }
                if($count == $limit)
                    break 2;
            }
        }
        $merged = array();
        foreach($leveled as $array)
            $merged = array_merge($merged, $array);
        return $merged;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function eventOut($animals, $limit)
{
    $j = 0;
    $returnAnimals = array();
    for($i=0; $j<$limit; ++$i) {
        foreach ($animals as $animal) {
            if (isset($animal[$i] && $j<$limit) {
                array_push($returnAnimals, $animal[$i]);
                ++$j;
            } else { 
                $extra++;
            }
         }
     }
     return $returnAnimals;
 }
```

or:

```
function eventOut($animals, $limit)
{
    $returnAnimals = array();
    $types = count($animals);
    $extra = $limit % $types;
    $numberOfAnimals = ($limit - $extra) / $types;
    foreach ($animals as $animal) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $numberOfAnimals) {
            if (isset($animal[$i])) {
                array_push($returnAnimals, $animal[$i]);
            }
            $i++;
         }
         if ($extra > 0) {
             array_push($returnAnimals, $animal[$i+1];
             $extra--;
         }
     }
     return $returnAnimals;
 }
```

I have no time debugging the crap out of it, but this would be the basic function you would need?

Comment: The first answer has 3 problems, undefined $extra and, mixing the animals, and unlimited execution if the animals are less than the limit. the second one doesn't work as expected either, but thanks for the effort!